# php access object values

Tags: php, object

EDIT: Thanks everyone. I didn't even notice it was private lol, so I changed them from private to public, now it should be accessible... question now is how can I access the value of say 'backpackPosition'? thanks again!

```
TF2Inventory Object
(
[fetchDate] => 123456123
[items] => Array
    (
        [60] => TF2Item Object
            (
                [equipped] => Array
                    (
                        [scout] => 1
                        [sniper] => 1
                        [soldier] => 1
                        [demoman] => 1
                        [medic] => 1
                        [heavy] => 1
                        [pyro] => 1
                        [spy] => 1
                    )

                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => custom employee number
                                [class] => set_employee_number
                                [value] => 0
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => cannot trade
                                [class] => cannot_trade
                                [value] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [backpackPosition] => 61
                [className] => tf_wearable
                [count] => 1
                [defindex] => 170
                [id] => 535518002
                [level] => 20
                [name] => Primeval Warrior
                [quality] => unique
                [slot] => misc
                [tradeable] => 
                [type] => Badge
            )

        [43] => TF2Item Object
            (
                [equipped] => Array
                    (
                        [scout] => 0
                        [sniper] => 0
                        [soldier] => 0
                        [demoman] => 0
                        [medic] => 0
                        [heavy] => 0
                        [pyro] => 0
                        [spy] => 0
                    )

                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => cannot trade
                                [class] => cannot_trade
                                [value] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [backpackPosition] => 44
                [className] => tf_wearable
                [count] => 1
                [defindex] => 471
                [id] => 535518003
                [level] => 50
                [name] => Proof of Purchase
                [quality] => unique
                [slot] => head
                [tradeable] => 
                [type] => Hat
            )

        [42] => TF2Item Object
            (
                [equipped] => Array
                    (
                        [scout] => 1
                        [sniper] => 1
                        [soldier] => 1
                        [demoman] => 1
                        [medic] => 1
                        [heavy] => 1
                        [pyro] => 1
                        [spy] => 1
                    )

                [attributes] => 
                [backpackPosition] => 43
                [className] => tf_wearable
                [count] => 1
                [defindex] => 278
                [id] => 541628464
                [level] => 31
                [name] => Horseless Headless Horsemann's Head
                [quality] => unique
                [slot] => head
                [tradeable] => 
                [type] => Hat
            )

        [59] => TF2Item Object
            (
                [equipped] => Array
                    (
                        [scout] => 0
                        [sniper] => 0
                        [soldier] => 0
                        [demoman] => 0
                        [medic] => 0
                        [heavy] => 0
                        [pyro] => 0
                        [spy] => 0
                    )

                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => cannot trade
                                [class] => cannot_trade
                                [value] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [backpackPosition] => 60
                [className] => tf_wearable
                [count] => 1
                [defindex] => 115
                [id] => 548155039
                [level] => 10
                [name] => Mildly Disturbing Halloween Mask
                [quality] => unique
                [slot] => head
                [tradeable] => 
                [type] => Holiday Hat
            )
```

Comment: Are you accessing it from outside the scope of the class? The point of private instance vars is that they can't be seen by anything else.

Comment: You can't access private members of a class. That is why they are private.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981878/how-would-i-access-this-object-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private members are just that - private.  Only the class they belong to can access them.  If you want to be able to retrieve their values, you need to either make them protected (and thus available to parent and children classes) or public (available to all classes).  Another option is to write some getters, functions that look like

```
public function get_slot() {
    return $this->slot;
}
```

or use the `__get()` magic function to make a general getter that looks like

```
public function __get($name) {
    return $this->$name;
}
```

More info can be found in the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Though, making a getter magic method really defeats the whole purpose of private/protected variables.

Comment: Not always.  The __get() method could clone the variable it's returning, making the private/protected variable effectively read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Those items are only accessible by the object itself.  You will have to modify the code for that class and provide an accessor method, or change their scope.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need accessor method on each object in order to access the values. Since they are private they can only be accessed within each of the classes they belong.

Answer (score 0):

The private properties just can be accessed from inside the object itself. To access try to use `$this->propertyName`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the scenario of trying to get around an imposed private data restriction, for instance if you are by chance working with a library which you don't have access to change the privilege level of the class member, then there is a work around. Presuming the object is serializable/unserializable then consider:

```
<?php
class SourceProtected {
    private $foo = 'one';
    protected $baz = 'two';
    public $bar = 'three';
}   

class SourceUnprotected {
    public $foo = 'blah';       
    public $baz = 'two';
    public $bar = 'three';
}


$protected = new SourceProtected();
$unprotected = new SourceUnprotected();
var_dump(serialize($protected), serialize($unprotected));
```

The output looks something like:

```
string(110) "O:15:"SourceProtected":3:{s:20:"?SourceProtected?foo";s:3:"one";s:6:"?*?baz";s:3:"two";s:3:"bar";s:5:"three";}"
string(92) "O:17:"SourceUnprotected":3:{s:3:"foo";s:4:"blah";s:3:"baz";s:3:"two";s:3:"bar";s:5:"three";}"
```

So one solution, is to create a duplicate class that changes the privilege level on the variables to all public. Then serialize the working object, convert*** the serialized class to your versions, then simply unserialize the string and you'll have a working object of your class type with unlimited access.

Obviously the convert method is where you'll have to do some foot work. You'll need to either build a generalized parser which can handle any case or you can code a hacky works just for your specific use case series of str_replaces.

Answer (score -2):

you should see first object oriented php http://www.google.sk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=object%20oriented%20php&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CGQQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftalks.somabo.de%2F200703_montreal_oop.pdf&ei=k3EUT8HnGYHHswbi09A6&usg=AFQjCNEjsA2JgbGQfxnQ26XxTtFuHmvGIA&sig2=Vw4d7aD2GhulZYAM892EKA